# Why does keyup not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my input text fields to focus next in line when keyup.

jQuery code:

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) {
    $("<input>", {
        "class":"anBox",
        size: 1,
        maxlength: 1
    }).appendTo('#answerLine_' + counter);
};
$(".anBox").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('.anBox').focus();
    }
});
```

Here is a: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qygB2/109/)

Comment: So what happens? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free pie?

Comment: Free fiddle _http://jsfiddle.net/qygB2/118/_

Comment: Thank very you for the corretion :)

Comment: @Doorknob it didnt focus next input field.

Answer (score 4):

Your usage of `.next()` is incorrect. The `.next()` function looks for the next *sibling* of the element(s) that are in the current set, optionally also checking that the next sibling matches the selector provided.

Your `<input>` elements are in different `<span>` elements, though, so they aren't siblings, and therefore can't be matched using `.next()`.

What you'll need to do is go from your current `<input>` (`$(this)`), to its parent (`.parent()`), to the next `<span>` element (`.next()` or `.next('span')`), then find the `.anBox` element inside of that (`.find('.anBox')`), then focus it (`.focus()`). That looks like this:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.anBox').focus();
```

Take a look at the [updated jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qygB2/115/).

Comment: +1. And the correct usage would be: `$(this).parent().next('span').find('.anBox').focus();`

Comment: @techfoobar Yep, posted my answer halfway through while I got the fiddle and explanation of the correct DOM traversal together.

Comment: While your answer is certainly right, I am curious where the spans are coming from. Isn't the OP just looping and appending 3 input fields? Where do the spans come from?

Comment: @Steve Did you look at the jsFiddle linked in the question? The `<span>` elements are the HTML elements they start out with, and then the `<input>` elements are appended (one to each of the spans) as part of the loop.

Comment: D'oh. Just realized that he has the counter in the element id. I thought they all get appended to the same element. That's why I shouldn't check SO on your iPhone when you can't use all the debugging tools. :(

Comment: @JW_ No problem. If you found any of the answers helpful you can accept one of them to indicate that it was of the most use to you.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I still have problems when I try to implement this.

`for (var counter = 0; counter < answerLen; counter++) {`
`               var anbox = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({`
                  type : 'text',
                  class : 'anBox',
                  size : '1',
                  maxlength : '1'
               });
               anbox.appendTo('#answerLine_' + i);
            }`

It seems that the input .anBox does not exist.. I have tried to console.log($('.anBox')); but none is found..

Comment: @JW_ The code in your jsFiddle works fine for creating the `<input>` elements, so not sure why you need to change it... The only thing you probably need to do is make sure it's wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` call.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes in the fiddle, but if I try to implement they are getting messed up on the page.. :/ The problem might be somewhere else..

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of .next() is incorrect.Try to use

```
$(this).parent().next('span').find('.anBox').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `.anBox` has no "next". The next `.anBox` is in another span. You have to [climb up one parent span, then go to the next span, and find an `.anBox` there](http://jsfiddle.net/qygB2/114/):

```
if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
  $(this).parent().next().find('.anBox').focus();
}
```

Also, you are comparing to `maxLength` which is always "1" in your script. Your next input box will only focus if you pressed "1"

Answer (score 0):

`next()` does not give you the next matching element in the DOM. It gives you only the next sibling, iff it matches what you pass as the selector.

For getting what you are after, you can use the [nextInDOM()](http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/) utility (*Disclaimer: I am the author*) and use it like:

`$(this).nextInDOM('.anBox').focus();`